# Regular expression to get parse text .net

Tags: .net, regex, winforms, parsing

I have a textual content like this

> some text [some text] another text [some text] some more text [some text] another
>   text [some text] the ending of it

I need a regular expression to capture all the `[*]` as group. So I would have the output as this

> [some text] [some text] [some text]

but when I tried this

```
[(.*)]
```

I only get one group, that is

> [some text] another text [some text] some more text [some text]
>   another
>   text [some text]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex is

```
\[[^\]]+\]
```

The C# string would be

```cs
@"\[[^\]]+\]"
```

Apply with the global flag to match all occurrences.

```
\[        # a literal "["
[^\]]+    # any character that's not a "]", at least once
\]        # a literal "]"
```

Comment: thanks, but what it i need to capture nested brackest as one, e.g if i have `some text [some text[inside text] some text] another text [some text[inside[more inside] text]]`. in this case, it should group only on the outermost brakkets e.g it would capture `[some text[inside text] some text]` as one group and `[some text[inside[more inside] text]]`

Comment: @Smith This is impossible with regex. (And with "impossible" I mean just that, it's not a convenient exaggeration.) For this problem you need to write a parser that counts brackets and is aware of nesting levels.

Comment: well i will dig further, i don't believe its impossible

Comment: Yes, it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to escape the `[]` as they are special symbols. Will this work?
`(\[.*?\])`